# Why does RAM cost more than flash memory?

Tags: memory, flash, storage

Why is the price/gigabyte for RAM higher than the one for flash memory, even though flash is more complex because it's non-volatile? Is it only because RAM needs to work at higher speeds?

Comment: *"Why is the price/gigabyte for RAM..."* -- The term *"RAM"* is not specific enough to make a sensible question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short and simple answer is:

In general, to implement data flash you need less transistors than to implement DRAM (main memory).

DRAM, on its turn, takes less transistors to implement than SRAM (cache memory). More transistors take up more die space (in general) and are thus more expensive.

Another difference between RAM and flash is that RAM can't tolerate faulty bits and flash can. A flash device normally contains more memory internally than necessary and the on-board controller hides the sections that contain faulty bits so you only get to see the flash that has no faults.

That means that manufacturers have to throw away RAM that contains faulty bits but can downgrade flash memory to a lower capacity. This increases the yield of the flash production process.

As you already mentioned, speed is also a contributing factor. In general, higher speed memory requires a more complex design and requires more energy (devices will become hotter).

For more details see the following books:

- [The Cache Memory Book](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=-7oOlb-lCpMC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=memory%20die%20size%20per%20bit&source=bl&ots=oVjyqJ02Yt&sig=MCgpQiThvIemfmaZWtDLCHCmZhk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwATgKahUKEwihwLyhk53HAhXJkJQKHdn1Bt4#v=onepage&q=memory%20die%20size%20per%20bit&f=false)
- [CMOS Processors and Memories](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=2E0r6BRo2VkC&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=memory%20die%20size%20per%20bit&source=bl&ots=mllHtca3f4&sig=ecvYybKjqrWEeuGJkKjzcQxWQoo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwCWoVChMIpvm81JKdxwIVZ1umCh2BJAWc#v=onepage&q=memory%20die%20size%20per%20bit&f=false)

Comment: I'd also guess higher speed memory necessarily requires a more exact clock mesh; the same amount of skew on a flash chip might proportionally be small enough not to matter, but on some blazing-fast SRAM that amount of skew would mean you need to throw the entire thing away.

Answer (score -1):

Flash is not more complex.

Ram have higher frequency working speed, it require refreshing constantly, it use other technology

In modern word it cost of something mostly depend of availible technologies and process cost, not complexity.

Comment: SSD is nowhere near $2 per Gb. You can buy a 1TB Samsung 850 EVO for $345, making it about $0.35 per GB. 64 GB memory cards are about $23, making the cost similar. And as you've shown, RAM is massively more expensive. Note also that Gb is not the same as GB.